# Buffered and Unbuffered inputs in C

Tags: c, input, buffer

Is there any way to figure out whether the `input` is `buffered` or `unbuffered` (Apart from manual pages.)? Cant we figure out by looking at the names of the functions?
Also for `echoing` and `nonechoing...`
For quick reference where to find the list which has the details of `Buffered`, `Unbuffered`, `echoing` and `nonechoing` inputs?

Comment: Sorry, you said "apart from man pages". Comment removed. FYI setbuf may be helpful.

Comment: I don't think there's a portable way to detect whether a particular open file stream (`FILE *`) is buffered or unbuffered. Why would you need to know, anyway?

Comment: I dont want to know it at run time. But is there any way to know which function is buffered or unbuffered or echoed or non-echoed... 
By looking at a function name, is it possible? Or else any link which tells about which function is buffered and which one is not would help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*All* `stdio.h` functions for reading from a `FILE` may exhibit *either* "buffered" or "unbuffered" behavior, and *either* "echoing" or "non-echoing" behavior.  What controls these things is not which function you use, but settings on the stream and/or its underlying file descriptor.

- The standard library function [`setvbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) can be used to enable or disable buffering of input (and output) by the C library.  This has no effect on buffering by the operating system.  There are three possible modes: "fully buffered" (read or write in substantial chunks); "line buffered" (buffer until a `'\n'` character is read or written, but not beyond that); and "unbuffered" (all reads and writes go to the OS immediately).
- The default buffering for new `FILE` objects (including `stdin` and friends) is implementation-defined.  Unixy C libraries generally default all `FILE`s to fully buffered, with two exceptions. `stderr` defaults to unbuffered.  For any other `FILE`, if `setvbuf` has not been used on it at the time of the first actual read or write, and [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) is true for the underlying file descriptor, then the `FILE` becomes line-buffered.
- Some C libraries provide extension functions, e.g. [`__flbf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/__flbf) and friends on Linux and Solaris, for reading back *some* of the settings controlled by `setvbuf`.  Keep in mind that, as described above, the buffering mode can change upon the first actual read or write, if it hasn't been explicitly set.

If input is from a file, `setvbuf` is the only knob you have.  If input is from some sort of communication channel, there may be other knobs:

- On POSIX-conformant systems (read "everything except Windows"), a program can request any of several different modes for terminal input.  Of these, the most important distinction to make is [between "canonical" and "noncanonical"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html).  A terminal in canonical mode exhibits both buffering and echoing.  (This buffering is *separate* from the buffering the C library may do if `setvbuf` has not been used to disable it.)  Non-canonical mode allows you to toggle buffering and echoing separately.  The [low-level POSIX terminal interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface.html) is extensive, complicated, and allows you to both read and write all of these settings.
- If you think you want to put the terminal in a non-canonical mode, before writing a bunch of code against the low-level POSIX API for doing so, you should first consider whether the [`readline`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [`ncurses`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library would make your life easier.
- If you are reading from a pipe, you are at the mercy of whoever is writing to it; you cannot control the size of the chunks you get.
- If you are reading from a socket, you *may* be able to exercise some control over the size of the chunks you get by careful use of [`recvmsg`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg), but there are no guarantees.
- I don't know how it is on Windows.

Comment: +1 After reading your post I deleted mine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have couple of question for you.
Who sets the setvbuf for the standard library functions? (Are the standard library functions are by default line buffered?)
Using which function we can set the echoing and non-echoing functionality?
Some examples on controlling buffer using setvbuf would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @NishithJainMR I have added an explanation of the default `stdio` buffering behavior to the text of the answer.  I don't want to provide any more information about echoing than I have here, because I don't want to give the impression that turning off echoing is simple.  The actual system calls to do it are straightforward, but they have a whole bunch of surprising consequences.  In nearly all cases one should use `ncurses` or `readline` instead; these provide a much higher-level API that smooths over all those consequences.

Comment: On windows (mingw at least) all files are fully buffered, including `stdout` and even `stderr`; `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` are available.

Answer (score 4):

**ISO/IEC 9899-1999 C99 Language Standard**

**5.1.2.3 Program execution**

...

5) The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in
7.19.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output
appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to
a program waiting for input.
...

**7.19.3 Files**

...

3) When a stream is unbuffered, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the
destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and
transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is fully buffered,
characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
a buffer is filled. When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be
transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is
implementation-defined, and may be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions.
...

7) At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly
— standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing
conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially
opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
to an interactive device.

Answer (score 2):

You can associate a buffer with a file, including `stdin`, with `setvbuf()`. You can change the buffering mode to full, line, or none.

Comment: True, but this doesn't help detect whether a particular open stream is buffered or unbuffered, which is what I think the question is asking about.